# how can i check the size on a server?

Tags: linux, http, curl

how can I check the size of file on server in bytes?

i need to do it for [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518968/is-it-possbile-to-dowload-one-part-of-a-file-from-web)

Comment: Has already been answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518968/is-it-possbile-to-dowload-one-part-of-a-file-from-web/3519083#3519083

Comment: yes one on SO is sovled. but I want to know how to check the file size to use it.

Comment: Ahh... OK, I misread the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a HEAD request and check out the *Content-Length* http header. With curl that would be `curl -I http://yoururl.com/yourfile.jpg`